# Why does bmiHeight/bmieWeight return a 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile

I am trying to create a BMI calculator in swift playgrounds for an iOS development challenge and it works using all other arithmetic but only returns 0 when attempting to divide the bmiHeight/bmiWeight

```
import UIKit

func bmiCalculator(height : Int, weight : Int) -> String {

    let bmiHeight = height * 703
    let bmiWeight = weight * weight
    let bmiEquation = bmiHeight / bmiWeight


    if bmiEquation > 25 {

        return "Your BMI is (bmiEquation). You are  overweight"
    }

    else if bmiEquation > 18 &&  bmiEquation <= 25 {

        return "Your BMI is (bmiEquation). You are in the normal range"
    }

    else {

        return "Your BMI is (bmiEquation). You are underweight"
    }
}

print(bmiCalculator(height: 72, weight: 230))
```

Comment: Since integers can only store... integer values, there's no way to store any digits after the decimal point. Thus, integer division "truncates" down. So 5/2 = 2 (not 2.5, since there's no way to represent 2.5 as an int), 1/10 = 0 (since there is no 0.1), etc. To remedy this, you need to do your division using a type that supports decimals, such a `Double`.

Comment: I got it solved, I just switched the height and the weight values in where there were top be placed in the equation